# Java/Eclipse console shows replacement character

Tags: java, eclipse, jconsole

This class prints a defined amount of chars to the Eclipse console. But for specific chars it shows the unicode replacement character after 16384 bytes.

[image]

I'm wondering why is that? It doesn't happen for ASCII chars, but also doesn't happen for other unicode chars.

I'm using Eclipse Oxygen.1 Release (4.7.1) and Java SE 8 [1.8].

```
package main;

public class Main {

    // 2 REPLACEMENT CHARACTERS (�) after 16.384 bytes
    // http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b7/index.htm
    // Hex: 0xC2 0xB7
    static final String SIGN1    = "·";

    // No replacement characters
    // http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25CF/index.htm
    // Hex: 0xE2 0x97 0x8F
    static final String SIGN2    = "●";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String out ="";

        for (int i = 1; i <= 8600; i++) {
            out += SIGN1;

            // issue only occurs when \n is added
            if (i % 100 == 0) {
                out += "\n";
            }
        }

        System.out.println(out);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your IDE encoding configuration?

Comment: @Bernat everything is set to utf8.

Comment: Even [this](https://decoding.wordpress.com/2010/03/18/eclipse-how-to-change-the-console-output-encoding/)?

Comment: @Bernat yes, it's also UTF8 (Inherited). The strange thing is, if I change it to ISO-8859-1 I don't have the replacement chars.

Comment: ah, I found the issue. It seems to be a bug with the console buffer. See: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=266658#c1